# understanding Image Classification ResNet accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

Currently I have trained a ResNet50 for image classification with a 85% classification accuracy. The doubt that I am encountering is that, when I input an image that is far away from the training set, instead of getting a 0% confidence in all the labels, I am getting 100% in one of the labels.

In other words if I train my network to classify dogs and cats it classifies correctly with 90-99% accuracy in between the image class but if I present a bicycle it tends to output 100% confidence for one of the labels.

Is this the correct expected response from the network?

If so, how can I make the network report 0% confidence in my training label set in case I present an image that is outside the training set?

Thanks

Comment: did you train the network from scratch or you used the pretrained network? I suggest you do the training on a pretrained network. Deep networks like resnet will get overtrained sometimes if you don't gather proper training data.

Comment: Hi Masoud, thank you for your input. I did used a pre-trained network. This is what I used: base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape= (IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH,3))


x = base_model.output
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)

predictions = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

model.summary()

Comment: You train multiclass or multilabel classifier? And which loss function was used?